# Can I use Autofac 3.5 with .NET 4.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.0, autofac

Unfortunately, I'm stuck with a Windows Server 2003 server for a few more months.  This only runs the .NET Framework up through version 4.

Can I use Autofac 3.5 with .NET 4?

I see Autofac 3.5 is required for the Autofac MVC 5 library, and Microsoft's MVC 5 is a .NET 4.5 library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Autofac 3.5 library](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac/) does not require .NET 4.5, so yes, you can absolutely use Autofac 3.5 with .NET 4.0.

The [Autofac MVC5 integration library](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Mvc5/) does not support .NET 4.0.

Comment: Thanks.  It wasn't immediately apparent on their website what the requirements are.  Nuget listings don't post this often, either.

Comment: @ps2goat - true, it should've been documented better. One easy way though is, look into the nuget packages. Libraries will be stored in the supported platform folders. Net40, net45, or both if both platforms are supported.